# Turn-based Multiplayer Game cannot finish in Google Play Game Services

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm using a turn based multiplayer game. 
Player 1 starts the game, Player 2 ends. But I always get errors.

This is the code for Player 2:

```
String playerId = Games.Players.getCurrentPlayerId(getApiClient());
String myOponentId = mMatch.getParticipantId(playerId);

opponentResult = new ParticipantResult(myOponentId,
                    ParticipantResult.MATCH_RESULT_WIN, 1);
            creatorResult = new ParticipantResult(playerId,
                    ParticipantResult.MATCH_RESULT_LOSS, 2);

Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.finishMatch(getApiClient(), mMatch.getMatchId(),mMatch.getData(), creatorResult,opponentResult )
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<TurnBasedMultiplayer.UpdateMatchResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(TurnBasedMultiplayer.UpdateMatchResult result) {
                        processResult(result);
                    }
                });
```

Log:

```
E/Volley﹕ [2816] a.a: Unexpected response code 400 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/turnbasedmatches/ChEKCQixqozpwBoQAhACGAAgARDEt9LOpreWivoB/finish?language=en_GB
E/cc﹕ Failed to finish match: null
W/cc﹕ {"code":400,"errors":[{"message":"Invalid participantId with value 108607338309210360902.","domain":"global","reason":"invalid"}]}
```

Using finishMatch like in the example SkeletonActivity.java is working, but does not produce a winner:

```
Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.finishMatch(getApiClient(), mMatch.getMatchId()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i messed up the nubers. have to set participant ids whichs is something like p_1 and not a number

myOponentParticipantId